# why isn't it possible to address a pointer using double ampersand?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
    int i=10,*j,**k,***l;
    j=&i;
    k=&j;
    l=&k;
    printf("%d",**(&(&i)));
    /* isn't it the same as **k ,
    because k=&j and j=&i */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As per chapter 6.5.3.2, `C11` standard, unary `&` operator

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

but,

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. *[..]* and the result is not an lvalue.

which is not an **lvalue**. so, the way of access `&(&i)` in your code is not valid. That is why, we need to use the intermediate pointer *variables*, which can be used as *lvalue* (supplied as an operand to unary `&`).

Note: the proper signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 4):

The same reason you can't get the address of e.g. an integer literal, it's not something that's stored anywhere.

A variable, such as for example `k`, is stored in memory, which is why you can use `&k` to get the address of where `k` is, in essence a pointer to `k`. That `k` itself is a pointer does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

`**(&(&i))` is not equal to `**k`. Its because `&i` will give the address of `i`, say `0x12345`. Now applying `&` again on it is invalid because `&` expects an lvalue as an operand but `0x12345` is a rvalue.

`*(&(*(&i)))` is equivalent to `**k`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&(&i)` is asking for the address *of the address* of `i`; such an operation is nonsensical.  An address does not have an address.

The *result* of the expression `&i` is not an *lvalue*; it does not occupy any memory such that you can write to it or take the address of it.